# ASP.net redirection via web.config

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config

I am new at ASP.net and I am trying to redirect just the contact us page to https. The rest should stay with http. In a way I was able to do this. My problem is that when I click home from the contact us page, it doesnt go back to http.. its remains https. The other links are fine.

Below are parts of my web.config. I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

```
<rewrite>
<rules>

<rule name="root to http" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="https://www.bpicards.com/" />
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.bpicards.com/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

<rule name="Redirect non-www to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="bpicards.com" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.bpicards.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="Cards-Details-54-slash" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="Cards/Details/54/" />
<action type="Redirect" url="/Cards/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="Cards-Details-54" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="Cards/Details/54" />
<action type="Redirect" url="/Cards/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="RealThrills-ItemDetails-155" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="RealThrills/ItemDetails/155" />
<action type="Redirect" url="/RealThrills/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="Contact Us" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="ContactUs" />
<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.bpicards.com/ContactUs/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>



<rule name="Cards" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="Cards" />
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.bpicards.com/Cards/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>


<rule name="Real Thrills" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="RealThrills" />
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.bpicards.com/RealThrills/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>


<rule name="BPI Buys" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="BpiBuys" />
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.bpicards.com/Bpibuys/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>


<rule name="Sip" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="Sip" />
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.bpicards.com/Sip/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>


<rule name="Calculators" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="Calculators" />
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.bpicards.com/Calculators/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>


<rule name="ApplyNow" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="ApplyNow" />
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.bpicards.com/ApplyNow/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>


<rule name="BPI Cards" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="BpiCards" />
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.bpicards.com/BpiCards/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>



</rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install and enable URL Rewrite Module for IIS7 and use a redirection rule in your web.config file.

You may want to check this link for some sample code.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1206943.aspx?HTTPS+to+HTTP+redirect+in+web+config